# How do you use an interface as data type for a property (from the value stack) in a Struts 2 action?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I have never used Struts before, so am not sure what I'm trying to do is possible.

I have an `Action` class, which has a `MyType` property:

```
public class Action /* extends ... */ {
  private MyType myType;
  // getters and setters and other members omitted

  public String doStuff() {
    myType.foo(); // NPE
    // ...
  }
}
```

I refactored the code (to implement the decorator pattern, blissfully unaware of Struts and its inner workings) and made `MyType` an `interface`, with `MyTypeImpl` providing its implementation.

Now, when the action gets called, `myType` is `null`, when in the past, it held an instance of `MyType` (now `MyTypeImpl`).

So, my question is basically: can I make Struts play nicely with that set-up, i.e. make it use `MyTypeImpl` for the property of `MyType` in the `Action` class, without having to change the actual web page? (In other words, how do I make this work while keeping the number of changes required to a minimum?)

Seeing how we have `struts2-spring-plugin` on the classpath, I assume Spring is injecting the value for `myType` at the end of the day, which makes me hopeful that it can somehow be configured? **Update 3:** After looking furhter into this, I don't think it has anything to do with Spring. Struts creates the properties automatically via value stuck from user input. These properties don't seem to be wired by Spring. (If they were, they'd be `prototype`s, but I don't see how their fields would be populated.) **`MyType` is *not* a service bean!**

**Update:** Here is an extract from Spring's config - it doesn't seem relevant as it doesn't mention `MyType`:

```
<bean id=“Action” class=“com.example.Action" scope="prototype">
    <property name=“fooService” ref=“fooService”/>
    <property name=“barService” ref=“barService”/>
</bean>
```

The snippet from the Struts config file that's relevant:

```
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
  <!-- ... -->

  <action name=“doStuff” class="Action" method=“doStuff”>
  <!-- several interceptors called, among them -->
  <interceptor-ref name="store"><!-- ... --><interceptor-ref/>
  <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"> 
  <!-- according to http://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html this calls
       ParametersInterceptor which is probably involved in the instantiation of it all… -->
  <!— several results defined —>
</action>
```

Can anyone with Struts experience say if what I am trying to do (have Struts use the implementation instead of the interface when injecting the object) is ***generally possible*** (e.g. by using annotations on `MyType myType`)? If the only way round this is to change Spring's autowiring type, is it possible to restrict that by package/class?

**Update 2:**
Spring might actually have very little to do with it all. In the website's source code, there is a form that has fields similar to these:

```
<input type="text" name="myType.foo" />
<input type="text" name="myType.bar" />
```

I haven't got the JSP in front of me, but I'm assuming it will actually use struts jsp tag library, e.g.

```
<s:textfield name="myType.foo" label="Random string" />
```

I have seen that if I used `implements ModelDriven`, I could specify

```
@Override
public MyType getModel() {
  return new MyTypeImpl();
}
```

However, that would "flatten" the properties from `MyTypeImpl` on the ValueStack, and if I understand correctly, I'd have to change the form elements' names accordingly, e.g. from `myType.foo` to simply `foo` for it to work. I can't do that; I need a solution that doesn't require me changing the forms/JSP.

Is there a way for the "normal"/regular (i.e. non-ModelDriven) approach to also define what object gets instantiated for `MyType` by Struts2?

Comment: Please post the Spring xml configuration

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question correctly, but if spring, struts and the struts-spring plugin are installed you can use the `javax.inject.Inject` annotation to get spring beans into the action. And you have of course to define your `MyTypeImpl` as current implementation of your `MyType` interface in the spring environment.

Comment: How Struts2 is related? You're declaring bean but not injecting `MyType` to it.

Comment: I thought it had to do with Spring, but it is actually standard Struts behaviour. `MyType` is an input parameter and thus part of the model that goes on the value stack. I do no longer think this has anything to do with Spring wiring/injection.

Answer (score 0):

Struts delegates autowiring of action bean to Spring. (Without entering in Struts internals and saying many words). Everything else is managed by Spring. Struts only calls Spring with certain parameters used by configuration.

If you ever used Spring, then you should know how autowiring works. I.e. you need to have configured a bean being autowired. By placing annotation `@Autowired` or use `@javax.inject.Inject` that Spring supports too.

```
public class Action /* extends ... */ {

  @Autowired
  private MyType myType;
  // getters and setters and other members omitted

  public String doStuff() {
    myType.foo(); // NPE
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then configure the bean (in Spring) of type `MyType`. That's it. In case if you have multiple implementation of the same type add the name to the component or the qualifier that allows to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, roman-c, but I'm not sure if Spring isn't a red herring here? `myType` is an input parameter and thus part of the model that goes on the value stack. I'll add an example of what the input form looks like to the question...

Comment: Nope, `myType` can't be used as an input parameter.